# adding 'click' effect on UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, effect

i have a `UIButton` that when I tap it, goes down giving effect of a `click/tap`.

[image: example]

My problem is that I have to add a `black border` around `UIButton`, but adding this keeps border static and it doesn't move down with the `UIButton`, the code that let me have click effect on `UIButton` is this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];

    CGSize size = self.bounds.size;
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGRect faceRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(faceRect.size, NO, 0.0);

    [[self faceColorForState:self.state] set];

    [self drawRoundedRect:faceRect radius:self.radius context:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *faceImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [[self sideColorForState:self.state] set];

    CGRect sideRect = CGRectMake(0, size.height * 1.0 / 4.0, size.width, size.height * 3.0 / 4.0);
    [self drawRoundedRect:sideRect radius:self.radius context:context];

    CGRect faceShrinkedRect;
    if(self.state == UIControlStateSelected || self.state == UIControlStateHighlighted) {
        faceShrinkedRect = CGRectMake(0, self.depth, size.width, size.height - self.margin);
    } else {
        faceShrinkedRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height - self.margin);
    }
    [faceImage drawInRect:faceShrinkedRect];
}
```

Comment: I recomment using canvaspod.io/ Its super simple.

Comment: why about placing a translating trasform on the button instead of custom drawing?

Comment: because if i apply a translating transform the border applied on layer still keep not moving... can you give me an example with a CGLayer?

Comment: if you translate the entire view the border should also move. Maybe you could add an image to your post and your intended layer hierarchy?

Comment: Not as fancy as drawing it yourself, but why not use two png files as the button background, one for normal state and one for active/tapped?

Comment: i've added gif image to show my problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're overcomplicating things using `drawRect:`. The easiest way to do this is to create 2 images for the background of your button, one with a black border. Then use:

```
[myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:<up-image>] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:<down-image>] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

You could re-use your code to create the images in code if necessary.
Maybe a category method on `UIImage` say:

```
+(UIImage *)buttonBackgroundImageWithColor:(UIColor *) color highlighted: (BOOL) highlighted
```

Comment: i prefer do not use two png because i should use different colour of button, so this method will let me use a lot of png file.

Comment: You can create UIImages in code with whatever colour you want and then assign them to the states. Overriding drawRect is almost never the right answer